# How to specify rows and columns for a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For matrix，I can use `matrix(nrow=5,ncol=100)` to specify rows an columns.

My question is, how can I deal with data frame if I want to specify rows and columns.

Comment: do you want to create the empty data frame with specified dimensions? then just wrap up the matrix call with `data.frame()`

Comment: @PiotrZieliński Same thing works for non-empty (by which I mean positive row-length) dataframes. I actually already had that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks!  @PiotrZieliński

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example with 0 rows and 3 columns. Of course, it could be any number of rows and columns (when I do this I'm usually creating an empty dataframe though).

Same basic thing works with `data.table`.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Date", "File", "User"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I included some nice-to-have options.

So, if you want 5 rows and 100 columns:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,5,100))
```

Comment: You really don't need `vector()` in there --- the end result is the same it you just remove it and only specify the `ncol` and `nrow` args. It would also be conceptually easier to do `setNames()` on the data frame output: `setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3)), c("Date", "File", "User"))` as you don't need to know anything about dimnames and row/col name ordering or that these have to be a list.... i also think you meant `data.frame` not `data.table`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Did you see the 2nd example? I gave a bare bones version and a version with nice-to-have options that have served a lot of my use cases in the past. I meant `data.table` when I said it ("the same thing works with `data.table` "). That's one of the reasons I like this; it's basically the same whether I do it for a DF or DT. Read back over the answer, I think you're confused.

Comment: Well, you did edit the thing about 50 times while I was writing the comment :-) My points about the complicated version still stand and no, I'm not confused about anything here, except your intention re data.table. It would make more logical sense to put that sentence at the end of your answer as it basically reads: "same thing works in data.table, here's an example using `data.frame()`" - i.e. it's confusing what you mean.

Comment: `matrix(5,100)` creates a matrix with 100 rows and 1 column, that is filled with 5s.

Comment: @lmo Typo, fixed. Thanks.